# How to split an array based on certain values or indexes?

Tags: php

I have this array

```
array:15 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 0
  2 => 0
  3 => "2018-10-20"
  4 => "2018-10-21"
  5 => "2018-10-22"
  6 => "2018-10-23"
  7 => "2018-10-24"
  8 => 0
  9 => 0
  10 => "2018-10-27"
  11 => "2018-10-28"
  12 => "2018-10-29"
  13 => "2018-10-30"
  14 => "2018-10-31"
]
```

and somehow I want to extract each group of values that exists between zero's values into a separate arrays.

I want the result to be something like.

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "2018-10-20"
  1 => "2018-10-21"
  2 => "2018-10-22"
  3 => "2018-10-23"
  4 => "2018-10-24"
]

array:2 [▼
 0 => "2018-10-27"
 1 => "2018-10-28"
 2 => "2018-10-29"
 3 => "2018-10-30"
 4 => "2018-10-31"
]
```

Comment: And what have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? That should not be too difficult

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a foreach loop:

```
$chunks = [];
$current_chunk = [];

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if ($item == 0) {
        if (count($current_chunk) > 0) {
            $chunks[] = $current_chunk;
            $current_chunk = [];
        }

        continue;
    }

    $current_chunk[] = $item;
}

if (count($current_chunk) > 0) {
    $chunks[] = $current_chunk;
}

var_dump($chunks);
```

See a demo [<kbd>here</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/JGYGD).

Answer (score 0):

```
array_reduce($array, function ($prev, $curr) {
if (count($prev) == 0 && $curr == 0) {
    return $prev;
}
if ($curr == 0) {
    array_push($prev, []);
    return $prev;
}
if (count($prev) == 0) {
    return array(array($curr));
}
    array_push($prev[count($prev) - 1], $curr);
    return $prev;
}, []);
```

Comment: [Better, but still a random empty array in the middle](https://i.imgur.com/IpAKahL.png)